WooCommerce REST API вывод информации о таварах
Пытаюсь разобраться с WooCommerce REST API. Смог с помощью postman получить все данные о товарах. Но не понимаю как это сделать в php или js. Использовал такой код
$woocommerce = new Client(
  'https://gte/wp-json/wc/v3/products',
  'key',
  'key',
  [
    'version' => 'wc/v3',
  ]
);

print_r($woocommerce->get('products'));

(естественно вместо ключей подставил данные из админки WP REST API).
Выводит такую ошибку:

Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: cURL Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое правильно реализовать. Использую open server на apache_2.4-php_7.2-7.4.

Я правильно понял, что WooCommerce REST API работает только с https протоколом?

Нет, WooCommerce REST API работает с обоими протоколами, но для http аутентификация будет отличаться, полистайте документацию, ну и если у Вас http, почему у Вас здесь https: https://gte/wp-json/wc/v3/products?

В документации единственное, что написано. Parameters example: oauth_consumer_key=abc123&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1 и Example signature base string: GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-json%2Fwc%2Fv3%2Forders&oauth_consumer_key%3Dabc123%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1.
Но где это использовать я ума не приложу. И в интернете я тоже ответа найти не могу.

Примеров нет наверное потому что все ставят сертификат и не морочат себе голову, а смысла в http аутентификации локально не так много, на сайте у Вас все равно вероятнее всего будет https. Да и пример следует искать не по WooCommerce, а по OAuth 1.0a. Ну так-то в документации помимо пары строк кода, есть еще много параграфов текста, где описаны шаги создания цифровой подписи) Но я думаю что будет проще добавить сертификат)

Да, есть такое ощущение. Спасибо большое за помощь)
